# Adicionar uma linha no fim da query em MS-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tenho uma query e ela devolve a seguinte tabela:

[image]

Gostaria de saber se é possível adicionar mais uma linha (Neste caso a 3) para fazer a diferença entre os dois anos.

Eu queria uma nova linha que desse a diferença dos dois valores daquele armazém, que neste caso, no X98 era de -721,86. Mas eu não sei bem como fazer :s

A query que tenho é a seguinte:

```
SELECT
    Armazem
    ,DatePart(YEAR, Data) as DataAno
    ,SUM(ISNULL(ADITIVADA,0)) as ADITIVADA
    ,SUM(ISNULL(X98,0)) as X98
    ,SUM(ISNULL(X95,0)) as X95
    ,SUM(ISNULL(XGAS,0)) as XGAS
    ,SUM(ISNULL(XGPL,0)) as XGPL
    ,SUM(ISNULL(XAGR,0)) as XAGR
    ,SUM(ISNULL(MISTURA,0)) as MISTURA
    ,SUM(ISNULL(XAQ,0)) as XAQ
    ,SUM(ISNULL(ADIESEL,0)) as ADIESEL
    ,SUM(ISNULL(ADBLUE,0)) as ADBLUE
    ,SUM(ISNULL(O95,0)) as O95
    ,SUM(ISNULL(O98,0)) as O98
FROM(
    SELECT
         TARMA as Armazem
        ,DataTotal AS Data
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'ADITIVADA'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 2 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'X98'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 3 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'X95'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 4 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XGAS'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 5 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XGPL'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 6 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XAGR'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 7 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'MISTURA'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 9 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XAQ'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 10 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'ADIESEL'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 11 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'ADBLUE'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 12 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'O95'
        ,CASE WHEN TCMB = 13 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'O98'

    FROM
    (
        Select
             VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.Armazem as TARMA
            ,ISNULL(SUM(vendaspos_linhas.QTD),0) as TQTD
            ,VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.FACT_VD as TFactVD
            ,vendasPOS_Cabecalhos.DATA as DataTotal
            ,CB_VendasPOS.combustivel as TCMB
        from CB_VendasPOS (nolock)
        join vendaspos_linhas (nolock) on vendaspos_linhas.autoreg=CB_VendasPOS.autoreg
        join VendasPOS_Cabecalhos (nolock) on VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.Prenumero=vendaspos_linhas.Prenumero
        join VendasPOS_Turnos (nolock) on VendasPOS_Turnos.CodTurnoAuto=VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.CodTurnoAuto

        where (MONTH(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) >= MONTH('2015-09-01 00:00:00') AND MONTH(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) <= MONTH('2015-09-01 00:00:00'))
        and (YEAR(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) >= YEAR('2014-09-01 00:00:00') AND YEAR(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) <= YEAR('2015-09-01 00:00:00'))
  and VendasPOS_Turnos.armazem='454'
  and FACT_VD NOT IN ('A', 'I', 'G', 'M')

        group by
            vendasPOS_Cabecalhos.DATA
            ,VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.Armazem
            ,VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.FACT_VD
            ,vendaspos_linhas.QTD
            ,CB_VendasPOS.combustivel

    )Res
    GROUP BY
    DataTotal,TARMA,TFactVD,TCMB
)ResF
Group BY
   Armazem, DatePart(YEAR, Data) 
ORDER BY
     Armazem, DatePart(YEAR, Data) ASC
```

Comment: Sim é possível.

Comment: É através do UNION?

Comment: Isso depende de como queres fazer e como tens a tua query. Pronto já tens uma resposta. Mas devias editar a tua pergunta e por mais informação.

Comment: Tem razão, já editei a pergunta

Answer (score 0):

Sim, eu já uso isto, veja um exemplo:
Caso: Tenho 2 funcionários e preciso do salário deles somados e apresentados como você descreveu:

```
SELECT CODIGO, SALARIO_TRABALHO FROM CLIENTES WHERE CODIGO in (55685, 447878)
UNION ALL
SELECT Null, SUM(SALARIO_TRABALHO) FROM CLIENTES WHERE CODIGO in (55685, 447878)
```

Agora basta adaptar seu SQL

Answer (score 0):

Infelizmente a consulta abaixo só irá funcionar no SQL 2005 ou superior.

Ela funcionar para múltiplos armazens, e irá comparar o o primeiro ano no histórico como o mais recente.

```
WITH CTE_Res AS (
    Select
        VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.Armazem as TARMA,
        ISNULL(SUM(vendaspos_linhas.QTD),0) as TQTD,
        VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.FACT_VD as TFactVD,
        vendasPOS_Cabecalhos.DATA as DataTotal,
        CB_VendasPOS.combustivel as TCMB
    from CB_VendasPOS (nolock)
    join vendaspos_linhas (nolock) on vendaspos_linhas.autoreg=CB_VendasPOS.autoreg
    join VendasPOS_Cabecalhos (nolock) on VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.Prenumero=vendaspos_linhas.Prenumero
    join VendasPOS_Turnos (nolock) on VendasPOS_Turnos.CodTurnoAuto=VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.CodTurnoAuto
    where 
        (MONTH(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) >= MONTH('2015-09-01 00:00:00') AND MONTH(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) <= MONTH('2015-09-01 00:00:00')) and 
        (YEAR(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) >= YEAR('2014-09-01 00:00:00') AND YEAR(VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.data) <= YEAR('2015-09-01 00:00:00')) and 
        VendasPOS_Turnos.armazem='454' and 
        FACT_VD NOT IN ('A', 'I', 'G', 'M')
    group by
        vendasPOS_Cabecalhos.DATA,
        VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.Armazem,
        VendasPOS_Cabecalhos.FACT_VD,
        vendaspos_linhas.QTD,
        CB_VendasPOS.combustivel
), CTE_ResF AS (
    SELECT
        TARMA as Armazem,
        DataTotal AS Data,
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 1 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'ADITIVADA',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 2 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'X98',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 3 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'X95',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 4 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XGAS',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 5 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XGPL',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 6 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XAGR',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 7 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'MISTURA',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 9 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'XAQ',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 10 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'ADIESEL',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 11 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'ADBLUE',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 12 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'O95',
        CASE WHEN TCMB = 13 THEN ISNULL(SUM(TQTD),0) END as 'O98'
    FROM CTE_Res as Res
    GROUP BY
        DataTotal,
        TARMA,
        TFactVD,
        TCMB
), CTE_Estoque_Group AS (
    SELECT
        Armazem,
        DatePart(YEAR, Data) as DataAno,
        SUM(ISNULL(ADITIVADA,0)) as ADITIVADA,
        SUM(ISNULL(X98,0)) as X98,
        SUM(ISNULL(X95,0)) as X95,
        SUM(ISNULL(XGAS,0)) as XGAS,
        SUM(ISNULL(XGPL,0)) as XGPL,
        SUM(ISNULL(XAGR,0)) as XAGR,
        SUM(ISNULL(MISTURA,0)) as MISTURA,
        SUM(ISNULL(XAQ,0)) as XAQ,
        SUM(ISNULL(ADIESEL,0)) as ADIESEL,
        SUM(ISNULL(ADBLUE,0)) as ADBLUE,
        SUM(ISNULL(O95,0)) as O95,
        SUM(ISNULL(O98,0)) as O98
    FROM CTE_ResF as ResF
    Group BY
        Armazem, 
        DatePart(YEAR, Data) 
), CTE_Estoque AS (
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Armazem ORDER BY DataAno) as OrdemAsc,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Armazem ORDER BY DataAno Desc) as OrdemDesc,
        Armazem,
        DataAno,
        ADITIVADA,
        X98,
        X95,
        XGAS,
        XGPL,
        XAGR,
        MISTURA,
        XAQ,
        ADIESEL,
        ADBLUE,
        O95,
        O98
    FROM CTE_Estoque_Aux as ResF
), CTE_Estoque_Com_Footer AS (
    SELECT 
        Estoque.Armazem,
        Estoque.DataAno,
        Estoque.ADITIVADA,
        Estoque.X98,
        Estoque.X95,
        Estoque.XGAS,
        Estoque.XGPL,
        Estoque.XAGR,
        Estoque.MISTURA,
        Estoque.XAQ,
        Estoque.ADIESEL,
        Estoque.ADBLUE,
        Estoque.O95,
        Estoque.O98
    FROM CTE_Estoque AS Estoque

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        EstoqueAnterior.Armazem as Armazem,
        null as DataAno,
        EstoqueAnterior.ADITIVADA - EstoqueAtual.ADITIVADA AS ADITIVADA,
        EstoqueAnterior.X98 - EstoqueAtual.X98 AS X98,
        EstoqueAnterior.X95 - EstoqueAtual.X95 AS X95,
        EstoqueAnterior.XGAS - EstoqueAtual.XGAS AS XGAS,
        EstoqueAnterior.XGPL - EstoqueAtual.XGPL AS XGPL,
        EstoqueAnterior.XAGR - EstoqueAtual.XAGR AS XAGR,
        EstoqueAnterior.MISTURA - EstoqueAtual.MISTURA AS MISTURA,
        EstoqueAnterior.XAQ - EstoqueAtual.XAQ AS XAQ,
        EstoqueAnterior.ADIESEL - EstoqueAtual.ADIESEL AS ADIESEL,
        EstoqueAnterior.ADBLUE - EstoqueAtual.ADBLUE AS ADBLUE,
        EstoqueAnterior.O95 - EstoqueAtual.O95 AS O95,
        EstoqueAnterior.O98 - EstoqueAtual.O98 AS O98   
    FROM CTE_Estoque AS EstoqueAnterior
    JOIN CTE_Estoque AS EstoqueAtual ON EstoqueAnterior.Armazem = EstoqueAtual.Armazem AND EstoqueAnterior.OrdemAsc = EstoqueAtual.OrdemDesc
    WHERE EstoqueAnterior.OrdemAsc = 1
);

SELECT * FROM CTE_Estoque_Com_Footer
ORDER BY Armazem, DataAno * -1 DESC -- hack para colocar a data NULL no final.
```

Fiz uso de [`CTE`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) para ajudar a organizar a sua consulta, tanto que as três primeiras CTEs são uma transcrição da sua consulta, caso realize a consulta abaixo vai obter o mesmo resultado da sua consulta original:

```
SELECT * FROM CTE_Estoque_Group
```

A CTE `CTE_Estoque` serve para adicionar uma coluna com `ordem ascendente (OrdemAsc)` e outra com `ordem descendente (OrdemDesc)` referente a Coluna `Armazem` em relação a coluna `DataAno`. Desta forma consigo identificar o primeiro ano (`OrdemAsc = 1`) e o ultimo ano (`OrdemDesc = 1`) e cruzar estas duas informações

A CTE `CTE_Estoque_Com_Footer` serve para exibir a sua consulta e adiciona linhas adicionais com a diferença entre o primeiro ano e o ultimo ano de cada armazém (caso tenha mais de um).

**P.S:**

Eu teria usado um [`PIVOT`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.90).aspx) no lugar destes `CASE`s com o `GROUP BY` utilizando na consulta `CTE_ResF` e `CTE_Estoque_Group`